# BSC: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node

Tags: web3js, ether, nodejs, bsc, web3-providers

I use this tutorial for run BSC node:

```
https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/beaconchain/light-client
```

But with web3 I get error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
```

My code:

```
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://my-ip:27147'));
web3.eth.isSyncing().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Do you try other eth command ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your node is not deployed. To save you some time, you can use the following code to check if the node is up and running.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:27147" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}'
```